# Отправить POST запрос на сервер с выполненными скриптами JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, post

При наборе текста в форму через SetAttribute сайт Стима выдаёт такую ошибку:
[image]
Получается, мне нужно набрать текст в форму, но при этом не используя SetAttribute.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("accountname").SetAttribute("value", login);
```

Comment: Не понимаю зачем вам это, ведь все поля формы заполняются человеком в браузере - клиенте, и `post/get` запросом отправляются на сервер. Собственно вопрос открыт - зачем ? от этого зависит сам код.

Comment: @DigitalCore Конкретно тот же Steam. При регистрации аккаунта стим, если человек копирует-вставляет логин, пароль, почту - то в итоге просто появится ошибка, т.к. что-то надо вводить самому

Comment: Через sendkeys не рационально, ничем другим заниматься за пк нельзя в этот момент

Comment: когда человек копирует вставляет работает `JavaScript`, или `Ajax` - (обработчик формы на стороне клиента) на сервер отправляется `Post` - запрос уже со всеми аргументами.  Если данные аргументы заполняются программно, то никакие `JavaScript`, или `Ajax` не участвуют. Приведите пример сайта формы, куда у вас не отправляются данные,  и пример кода как вы это делаете, если делаете вообще.

Comment: @DigitalCore Понял, как это работает. Я немного ошибался, ctrl+c и ctrl+v тут не причем. Я сначала попробовал сам зарегистрировать аккаунт копируя-вставляя, и это у меня получилось, но затем я попробовал зарегистрироваться, изменяя значение "value" и мне как раз выдало ошибку, которую я прикреплю в основной топик. В общем, мне нужно набрать текст в форму, но при этом не используя SetAttribute.

Comment: дайте ссылку на сайт, обычно кроме видимых полей `input` есть скрытые поля `input type="hidden"` в которые может заносится хеш видимых полей сессия, и другие параметры. При работе через браузер задавая новое значение полю вы не изменяете значение скрытых полей, ссылку на форму - ресурс

Comment: @DigitalCore https://store.steampowered.com/join/
Буду очень благодарен, если поможете)

Comment: Хорошо, не работает, если ввести данные программно с помощью `SetAttribute`. А работает ли, если ввести те же данные вручную именно в компоненте `WebBrowser`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если вводить вручную, но в том же WebBrowser, то всё получается, как надо.

Answer (score 0):

**Используйте в место [webBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx), компонент [Chrome](https://www.seleniumhq.org) для обработки JavaScript, Ajax.**

```cmd
Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 3.11.1
```

**Пример использования данного компонента:**

```csharp
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;

public static string GetHtml(string url)
{
    var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    var Driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    string html = Driver.PageSource;
    Driver.Close();
    Driver.Quit();
    return html;
}
```

Теперь можем заполнять поля после получения исходного кода с уже выполненными скриптами. Но у вас встанет задача `Captha` в `webBrowser` вы её не видели, так как её подгружает JavaScript.

Comment: Еле как подключил антикапчу к webBrowser'у, т.к. первый раз с ней работаю, а теперь похоже придется всё переделывать под selenium. Ну что-ж, буду пробовать, позже отпишу, получилось или нет, но спасибо за наставление.