# Получить html со страницы которая генерируется скриптом c#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

В проекте возникла потребность получать некоторые данные с сайта. Проблема в том что работать с апи я по определенным причинам не могу, а контент самого сайта генерируется скриптом. Накопал ответы с WebBrowser (именно который с винформ, больше возможностей в нем), оно то работает впринципе но только если у меня winform проект и на форме есть этот самый браузер. Если я инициализирую экземпляр WebBrowser и при этом на форме его нету, свойство body всегда = null. Нужно или заставить WebBrowser выдавать нужный контент(спрятать его как нибудь), или любым другим способом получать этот html.

В самом проекте wpf форма с кнопкой, на кнопке висит вот это:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new 
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
browser.Navigate("https://temp-mail.org/ru");
Thread.Sleep(10000); //думал мб не хватает времени прогрузить
MessageBox.Show(browser?.Document?.Body?.InnerHtml);
```

Уже решил другим способом(из коммнетов). Все же объясните если кто знает почему body = null.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745960/c-cefsharp-offscreen-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810998/Отправить-post-запрос-на-сервер-с-выполненными-скриптами-javascript/811144#811144

Comment: WebBrowser из Win forms может работать невидимым, его не обязательно добавлять в форму

Comment: лично у меня ничего без добавления на форму не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Все же объясните если кто знает почему body = null.

Вот поэтому:

> `Thread.Sleep(10000); //думал мб не хватает времени прогрузить`

Использовать *Thread.Sleep* для ожидания загрузки документа нельзя. *WebBrowser* - обертка над ActiveX-элементом Internet Explorer, которому для корректной работы требуется обработка сообщений в GUI-потоке. Вызов *Thread.Sleep* блокирует ее, так что хоть и документ успевает загрузиться "транспортным уровнем" за 10 секунд, WebBrowser не может среагировать на это и установить значение свойства *Document*. Чтобы все сработало, нужно ждать без прерывания обработки сообщений.

К сожалению, WinForms очень старая библиотека и у *WebBrowser* я не смог найти асинхронного метода загрузки, который бы позволял использовать *await*. Так что единственный (стандартный) способ - подписка на событие:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
    browser.Navigate("https://temp-mail.org/ru"); 
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((sender as WebBrowser).Document.Body.InnerHtml);
}
```

---

Чтобы реализовать ожидание более удобно, создадим вспомогательный метод для ожидания события с помощью *TaskCompletionSource*:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WinformsTest
{
    public class AsyncTools
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Получает объект Task, который может использоваться для ожидания срабатывания указанного события
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">Объект-источник события</param>
        /// <param name="evt">Имя события</param>       
        public static Task<object> GetTaskFromEvent(object o, string evt)
        {
            if (o == null || evt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Please pass non-null arguments");

            EventInfo einfo = o.GetType().GetEvent(evt);
            if (einfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("*{0}* has no *{1}* event", o, evt));
            }

            TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            MethodInfo mi = null;
            Delegate deleg = null;
            EventHandler handler = null;

            //код обработчика события
            handler = (s, e) =>
            {
                mi = handler.Method;
                deleg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(einfo.EventHandlerType, handler.Target, mi);
                einfo.RemoveEventHandler(s, deleg); //отцепляем обработчик события
                tcs.TrySetResult(null); //сигнализируем о наступлении события
            };

            mi = handler.Method;
            deleg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(einfo.EventHandlerType, handler.Target, mi); //получаем делегат нужного типа
            einfo.AddEventHandler(o, deleg); //присоединяем обработчик события
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда ожидание загрузки документа можно осуществлять с помощью *await* (.NET 4.5+):

```
var task = AsyncTools.GetTaskFromEvent(webBrowser1,"DocumentCompleted");            
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://example.com/");
await task;
```